# API call works fine after npm start but crashes at refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

There is an API call on `http://localhost:9000/testAPI`.

In **bin/www**:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '9000');
app.set('port', port);
```

in **routes/index.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

in **routes/testAPI.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/ocs_athletes.db');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.all('SELECT athlete_id, name, surname FROM Athlete', function (
      err,
      row
    ) {
     return res.send(row);
    });
  });

  db.close();
});

module.exports = router;
```

When the command `npm start` is run, the API works, going to `http://localhost:9000/testAPI` shows a JSON containing the data.

The problem appears when the page is refreshed. It says **Page cannot be reached** and in terminal it throws this error:

```
GET /testAPI 304 20.628 ms - -
undefined:0



Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/rares/Documents/Projects/ocsApp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/rares/Documents/Projects/ocsApp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/rares/Documents/Projects/ocsApp/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (/home/rares/Documents/Projects/ocsApp/api/routes/testAPI.js:12:11)
    at Statement.replacement (/home/rares/Documents/Projects/ocsApp/api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:25:27) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the api@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try putting ``console.log(res.headersSent);`` at regular intervals in your code, to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears in this case because of `db.close()`, that line shouldn't be in the code.

So it would work fine if it is like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/ocs_athletes.db');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.all('SELECT athlete_id, name, surname FROM Athlete', function (
      err,
      row
    ) {
     return res.send(row);
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

this error happens basically when your function is keeping continue processing the execution after your res.send() . you must use return for avoiding that :

```
return res.send()
```

Comment: so basically you say that it must be added `return`. I've tried like that and it behaves in the same way. It runs fine after I run `npm start` but crashes when the page is refreshed.

Comment: @LeoMessi why you are closing db instance after return statement? no point . you must throw your errors too

Comment: @babk abdkheir, you're right. after removing that line it doesn't crash anymore. I just followed a tutorial and it was like that

Answer (score 0):

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." is telling you that you're already in the `body` or completed state, but that some function tried to set a `header` or `statusCode`. When this error occurs, look for something that tries to send a header AFTER some of the body has been written. This could be callbacks that end up being called twice, or an error that arises after the body is sent.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that, added an if-else statement where it is checked if it has an error and `res.send()` is called only if there is no error. Still doesn't work. I don't know which is a callback here or which part is called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You are geting that error because there are some error in you request handler

You are using `db.each` method to access result of the question which you performed. The purpose of that method is to allows you to execute some special callback as define in the [documentation](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)

> The each() method executes an SQL query with specified parameters and calls a callback for every row in the result set.

As your needs in your request handler is to return as the body the result of the query you should use `db.all` instead of `db.each`. There isn't any special code which perform some treatment on each row of the result. You can simple return the entire set of rows.

The fact that in the callback of the `db.each` you are using `res.send` this presume as many rows the query you performed to you `sqlite` database your can will try to rerun `res.send. When this is performed on the first row of the query result It work perfectly but the second time It will try to resent the result which seam to override the response which as already been sent to the browser and It will trigger that error

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)

So to fix that you change your code like this

```
db.all('SELECT athlete_id, name, surname FROM Athlete', function(err, rows) {
   res.send(rows);
})
```

Comment: I've tried like that but it has the same behavior. Runs first time, at refresh it throws this error in back-end: `GET /testAPI 200 0.644 ms - -
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
`

Answer (score 0):

Only change loacalhost  name weather react or node.js

Like loacalhost:3000
Then you will have to change 4000